# ViewPager gallery scrolling smooth

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm making some kind of app which show picture in fullscreen in full resolution, and it supports swipe to change photo. I have implemented ViewPager following completly this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html . On my Nexus 5 it works good for screenshots and front camera's photo, but when i need to swipe to back camera's photo there is a huge lag( this photo's are around 2MB ). It is not problem to user wait a bit when picture is loading and than view it, but it is interupting to have this kind of lag. In Google app Photos there is no bug with swiping this photos.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the 2MB picture from the UI thread. You should try to pre-load the next/previous bitmap in a background Thread and load it. This is the bitmap loading class I use in the background.

```
private class LoadBitmapData extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Bitmap> {

        private Bitmap pictureBitmap;
        private ILoadBitmapData delegate;
        private double maximumWidth = 1024;

        public LoadBitmapData(ILoadBitmapData del){
            this.delegate = del;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... path){

            try{

                pictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path[0]);

                //make sure we don't load a tremendously huge picture and crash the app.
                if(pictureBitmap.getWidth() > 6000){
                    double desiredWidth = maximumWidth ;
                    int nh = (int) ( pictureBitmap.getHeight() * (desiredWidth / pictureBitmap.getWidth()) );
                    pictureBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pictureBitmap, 1024, nh, true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return pictureBitmap ;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Bitmap pictureBitmap ){
            delegate.assignBitmap(pictureBitmap);
        }


    }
```

Comment: No, I'm using AsyncTask and I have problem with it.